# Where/How to Create Reference Number

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I'm using Entity Framework and MSSQL...

I need to insert a custom reference number when a record is inserted. The format is `YYYY-01`, `YYYY-02`, etc but the sequential number needs to be reset when a new year begins.

For example `2011-01`, `2011-02`, `2012-01`

I'm curious if I should just go with a trigger or manage this with EF or ?

Having the sequential numbering reset each year has me a little confused...

Thanks for any advice!

**Update:**
Sorry, couldn't get the `Code` tag to work well with the markup

*--Variables*

DECLARE @year   *INT*,

        @seqNum *INT*;


*--Try to find if the [ComplaintCount] table already contains the current year*

SET @year = (SELECT [Count_Year]

             FROM   [ComplaintCount]

             WHERE  [Count_Year] = *YEAR*(*Getdate*()))


*--If the current year cannot be found in the [ComplaintCount] table, a new record for the current year needs to be made*

IF @year IS NULL

  BEGIN

      *--Get the Current Year and set the initial sequence number to start counting for the new year*

      SET @year = *YEAR*(*Getdate*());

      SET @seqNum = 1;


      *--Insert the new default values into the [ComplaintCount] table*

      INSERT INTO [ComplaintCount]

                  (count_year,

                   count_current)

      VALUES      (@year,

                   @seqNum);

  END

ELSE

  BEGIN

      *--We found a record already in the [ComplaintCount] table for the current year*

      *--Get the sequence number and increase it by one*

      SET @seqNum = (SELECT [Count_Current]

                     FROM   [ComplaintCount]

                     WHERE  [Count_Year] = @year) + 1


      *--Insert the new values into the [ComplaintCount] table*

      UPDATE [ComplaintCount]

      SET    [Count_Current] = @seqNum

      WHERE  [Count_Year] = @year;

  END


*--Its now safe to insert the correct reference number into the [Complaint] table*

UPDATE 
UPDATE [Complaint]

SET    [Complaint_Reference] = *CAST*(@year AS *VARCHAR*) + '-' + *CAST*(

                               @seqNum AS *VARCHAR*)

FROM   [Complaint]

       INNER JOIN inserted

         ON [Complaint].[PK_Complaint_Id] = inserted.[PK_Complaint_Id]

Comment: How many records per year are you expecting?  (roughly)

Comment: Probably around 2k. I'm working on a trigger to manage the reference number but it seems to be a terrible way to get it done.

Comment: Select CreatedYear + '-' + (IdField - ISNull((SELECT MIN(IdField) FROM db WHERE db.CreatedYear = CreatedYear), 0) + 1)

Comment: The hangup with that is that the id doesn't reset at the start of each new year.  You could add more math to calculate the diff but not without having to do counts of records on every insert which would cause a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a trigger.  Create a two column table that stores the year and the current record number and then uses a trigger to look up the current year, increment the count column by one, then return that count to the trigger.  Build logic into the trigger that if the new year doesn't exist, insert the new year record.  I know most people like to avoid triggers if possible but that's a pretty legit use of a trigger and way less processing than trying to count records on every insert.

Having a single row for every year and it's related count may also prove useful in the future when you're trying to audit a past year or answer BI questions.

Comment: Can you extend your answer? This the easy part but what about atomicity, creating sequence without gaps, automatic adding new year, etc.?

Comment: Adding new year is as simple as checking and adding if the year you are trying to increment doesn't have a record.  Atomicity?  with only 2k inserts per year I don't think that's going to be a problem for the sql engine to deal with.  Gaps?  If a record has an error, or is deleted by a user... there is going to be a gap... no different than an auto-generated sequential key issued by the engine.

Comment: So you say that if something bad will most like not happen you don't need to prevent that in your code? If two concurrent operations request id from sequence you can insert duplicate number. If two concurrent operations create new year you will have two sequences. If there is requirement on sequence without gaps the error should rollback changes in the sequence as well. 2k look like not much but it can also be 20x 100 records in async batch processing. This require much more then create table and trigger.

Comment: Since you are updating the increment at the same time you are returning the value you automatically get the guarantee that the transaction was "atomic" since a lock must occur in order to update.  As for gaps, if this is a requirement then you are correct, it would require a lot more code.

Comment: I didn't get the feeling from the question that he was looking for someone to write the trigger for him.  Just advice on if there was a better way.  My answer was, a trigger is legit in this usage scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated my question with some code. Haven't tested it yet but I think it'll do.